# Doubled Up Paragraphs

Tags: visual, steganography

There is more to this text than can be immediately seen. Find the answer hidden a layer inside

[image: Image associated with puzzle]

Give an answer as the text inside of the `answer\`in here - 4 words`/` that you find.

Hint

> [image: Hint]

Comment: Welcom to Puzzling SE!

Comment: @North Thanks, I hope this is a good enough puzzle

Comment: Are you sure the formatting is correct where it says "answer\.../"?

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος When you find the answer, it's text inside the word `answer\the answer will be here when you find the answer/`. It might not be necessary to have it twice

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is the answer:

> "answer\a deeper meaning inside/answer" ?  
> I took the text on the pastebin link:
>      ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄S ▄o   ▄m▄e▄▄▄ ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄█t▄▄▄h█i▀█▄█▀▀n██▀g▄▄ █ ▄▄▄ ██ ███ █ ▀▀▄▀▄▄ ▀▄▀██▄ █ ███ ██▄▄▄▄▄█ █ █ ▄▀█▀█ █ █ █▄▄▄▄▄█▄▄▄▄▄s▄▄▄▄▄e█▀▄▄█▄▀▄ ▄e▄ ▄m▄ ▄▄▀▀▀▀▄ ▄█ ▄▄  ▄█▀█▀▀▄▀███▄ ▀▄█▀▄▄█▄▄s█▀█  ▀▄▄▄ █▀▀ ▀▀▀▄▄▀▀ █ ▀█▄▄ ▀█ ▀██▄▀█▀▀█▀▀███  ▀██ █▄▀▄▀l▀ i█▀▄ ▀▄▀ k  ▀▀█▄▀██▀▀▄▄ ▄ ▄ █▄▄  ▄█▄▄▀█▄▀▀█ ▄▀▀█e▀█ 2▄█▄▀▄█ 9▀█ ▄  ██████ ▄ ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄ █ ▄ ▀██▄█▀█▄█ ▄ █▀▀▀▀█ ▄▄▄ █ ▄▀█ █▀▄ ▀▄ ▀█▄▄▄█▀▄  █ ███ █ ██▀▄▄  ▄▄ ▀█▄█▄▄▄▄ █▀█▄▄▄▄▄█ █  █  ▀█▀▄▀▄▀█  █ ▄▀
>  that @Gareth McCaughan found and converted it into a QR code...
> [image: QR code]
> ...which spewed those words into my phone.
> Amid the white and black blocks comprising the QR code (in text form) are the words "something seems like 29." On the 29th character of each line is where the line break needed to be.

Answer (score 8):

Partial Progress: overlaying the two paragraphs, we see something interesting:

> [image]
>  A few words are shifted, just a few pixels off. These words are:
>
> ```
>  cups, 6, Many, 2, 1, Rarely, ze, Xavier
> ```
>
> Additionally,
>
> ```
> cups, 6, 2, Rarely
> ```
>
> are shifted slightly in one direction, while
>
> ```
> Many, 1, ze, Xavier
> ```
>
> are shifted the other direction.

I'm not sure how to get an answer from that though

Comment: I realised I didn't really put any hint to where to go in the image, so a hint has been added to the question

Comment: How did you overlay the paragraphs since they have a white background?

Comment: Given the hint, the next thing would seem to be https://pastebin.com/c6M21RzX but (though you could kinda-sorta call what's visible there four words) it seems like there's at least one more layer to unpeel.

Comment: @user991003 if you have a graphics/image editor like Photoshop (I use ***free*** Gimp), you can either a) select all the white and delete it/convert it to transparency or b) make one layer semi transparent (50% Alpha).

Comment: I've failed, I expected the pastebin to be case sensitive so it uses the shifting to say upper or lowercase